# WriteAllText method returns the last row, instead of the entire rows of the file

Tags: c#, text, text-files, writealltext

I have a code that:

- reads a text file,
- replaces all "spaces" with ";",
- removes the repetition of the character ";"
- and saves a new file with all changes.

But instead of writing all the rows in the file, it writes only the last row.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
        Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
        
        string FilePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\download1.txt";
        string OutputhFilePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\download2.txt";

        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).ToList();
        
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            string line1 =  line.Replace(' ', ';');
            line1 = regex.Replace(line, ";");
            Console.WriteLine(line1);
            File.WriteAllText(OutputhFilePath, line1);
        }
        
            Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

[image: Text file:]

[image: Text file after code:]

Can someone help me with these? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you imagine what ```WriteAllText()``` does just by the name ? The first sentence of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1 may help. Maybe you look for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: You init line1 by `string line1 =  line.Replace(' ', ';');` and then you overwriting this value by `line1 = regex.Replace(line, ";");`. Is it expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [File.WriteAllText Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netcore-3.1) do:

> Creates a new file, write the contents to the file, and then closes
> the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

So you overwriting file in each line readed... You may use [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1) to  do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
    Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
    
    string FilePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\download1.txt";
    string OutputhFilePath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\download2.txt";

    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    lines = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).ToList();
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string line1 =  line.Replace(' ', ';');
        line1 = regex.Replace(line, ";");
        Console.WriteLine(line1);
        sb.AppendLine(line1);
    }
    
    File.WriteAllText(OutputhFilePath, sb.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: sb.WriteLine (line1) should be - sb.AppendLine (line1), but the rest works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need `File.AppendAllText()`.

You're overwriting each previous line with the new one, which is why you're only seeing the last input line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are outputting to the file after each line. What `File.WriteAllText` does is it always overwrites the target file with the latest data. What you need instead is to append to the file. Try for example the [`File.AppendText` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netcore-3.1).

However an even better solution is to use a `StringBuilder`, append all lines to it and then output the whole content (`builder.ToString()`) at once. This avoids excessive opening and closing of the file after each line.